# Calculating permutations taking too much time

Tags: python, performance, combinations, permutation, factorial

I am trying to generate 20! permutations and do some Logical operations on it. I switched to multiprocessing and as I increase the number of processes preportional to the number of cores the performance increases . 
I have managed a time of 25sec for 10! calculations on a 32 core system.
My final task is to do 20! in less than 2 hrs, I am thinking of GPU programming. Give suggestions for the approach I should follow

Comment: What do you mean "20! permutations"? Permutations of what?

Comment: You need a better solution to your core problem. Enumerating 20! permutations will always be slow. It is supposed to be slow!

Comment: Just to put the problem in perspective, 20! = ~10^18. On any machine, it will take more than 3 years to do it. GPU will do nothing for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
10! = 3628800  
20! = 2432902008176640000  
20!/10! = 670442572800
```

If it is require 25 sec to generate 10! permutations, it will require near 670442572800 times 25 sec. It will cost 531490 years. Please review your question.

Comment: this should be a comment to the question

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I do anything that involves a large number of permutations, I consider how I can possibly avoid recomputing values I've already computed while generating the permutations. One such approach is to use recursion. By using recursion, you can often calculate the first n possibilities once, and pass the computed value forward to all other function calls without recomputing it n! times. Then the next function call handles n-1 possibilities, and so on. The problem with this approach is the recursion itself can add a pretty large overhead with all the function calls, and prevents the compiler from inlining + applying further optimizations.

Given you say you have n! permutations, I'd assume that you're probably rearranging n items. If these permutations take awhile to generate each (aren't just simple addition/multiplication or something), one thing you could consider doing is (if possible), generate all possible k-item permutations, which is k! * (20 choose k), still quite smaller than 20! for small k. Then store this in something like a hash table or a sorted array, and then lookup the respective values for all the other (20-k)! * (20 choose k) permutations. If you are searching for some optimal value, try "subtracting" that out of each query into the lookup table (again, if possible), if there's an entry, then its for the optimal value.

Without further details about the problem, I'm afraid there isn't much more I can suggest.